# How do I open JSON files using the Text Editor

Tags: linked-data, text-editor

I've been working with Sverchok (**awesome** add-on), which allows you to import/export data in a few formats, including JSON. The import function in Sverchok's node editor only allows you to utilize text files that are pre-loaded in the Text Editor window, but the problem is that the Text Editor can't "see" JSON files, and none of the filter buttons seem to make this possible. Am I missing something pretty basic?

Comment: What if you disable filtering entirely? (click the funnel icon to the left of the filter options)

Comment: we (team sverchok) should allow json to picked from disk and have the option to update the disk-read at low frequency at least (for dynamic json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to see files of any unexpected format (including JSON) is to disable filtering (click on the funnel!)

[image: Funnel button is used to filter visibility by file type]